# Problems with Dutch translations

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I installed Kubuntu 16.04 in Dutch. When starting the first time I got the message "can not start Plasma 5". I found a solution in
[Kubuntu 16.04 Plasma can not start after fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761801/kubuntu-16-04-plasma-can-not-start-after-fresh-install/762007#762007)
There it is said:

> The problem seems to be that the Dutch translations (kde-l10n-nl) of
>   KDE conflicts with plasma-desktop. Forcing the reinstallation of
>   plasma-desktop in a TTY fixed the issue

But now I receive messages saying that the languages support is incomplete and that supplementary packages must be installed. When I allow the installation, then it always fails. The last message I see in a flash is something as "problems with dependencies". Is it dangerous to work with the Dutch translations? How can I get them right without having interferences with the rest?

Kubuntu 1604 on ASUS laptop X756UB with dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-l10n-ru/+bug/1576455) #1576455 "SRU KDE-language-packages-mismatch". Even though it took a longer while, the subject should have been settled by now.

The packages were stuck quite a while in the "proposed-queue". It's not the dutch language alone, but any language was affected. So the packages **should** arrive now via normal updates. Even during installation, if option was ticked as valid.

Comment: This is the message I was waiting for. Today the installation of the supplementary language package (kde-l10i-nl) has succeeded.