# Stuck on Black Screen with Cursor Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: boot, nvidia, kubuntu, kde

I was in video class and all sudden I was getting black screen.

I use to boot into login screen. Enter my username and password but I cannot get into login screen.

These are pictures I took with my phone.

[image]
[image]

[image]

***UPDATE****

I cleared all Nvidia Drivers install onto my laptop using:

```
Sudo apt remove —-purge ‘nvidia*’
```

afterwards, I’ve checked any others “Nvidia” showing up by running search:

```
sudo dpkg -l |grep ‘Nvidia*’
```

Everything been cleared. I’ve check dkms status and Nvidia is not there either.

Reboot my computer > pressed CRTL + ATL + F2

Performed fresh install Nvidia-driver-470:

```
sudo apt install Nvidia-driver-470
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
```

I’m still getting this message:

```
  [65.039787] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
```

I don’t understand why I am still getting this error message:

```
   root@Omen: /home/krillavilla# ubuntu-drivers list
HARNING:root: _pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510-server: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level
HARNING:root: _pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level
```

After I remove Nvidia 510 driver. Forgive me I am updating this on my IPhone screen grammar.

***UPDATE***

So, I am making progress at least.
I reinstall sddm:

```
sudo apt install —-reinstall sddm
sudo reboot
```

It boot into my desktop screen:

[image]

When I enter my user Id and password,
It’s loaded:

[image]

Then, I got black screen again but I know I am at the desktop screen because I can run search query:

[image]

I opened Software & Updates window and reinstall Nvidia driver 510 and open Discover and it ran updates but it didn’t help

***UPDATE***

I tried reinstalling Kubuntu and plasma desktop:

```
sudo apt install —-reinstall Kubuntu-desktop kde-* && sudo apt install -f
```

using this article I found:

[fresh install of Kubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761801/kubuntu-16-04-plasma-can-not-start-after-fresh-install)

After installation, I figure I need to restart desktop, so I follow these instructions:

```
For KDE > 5.10
kquitapp5 plasmashell || killall plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
```

From this link:

[Restart KDE Desktop without logging out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out)

Now, it stuck here but I can cancel the process:

[image]